# Can I learn to RHCSA on EC2

Tags: centos, amazon-web-services, redhat

I have MacBook with M1 processor and I want to learn to RHCSA exam. There are no ARM distributions yet and I can't create local environment, would it be ok to provision EC2 centOS instance? I'm just afraid that I won't be able to recreate some test cases.

Comment: Actual RHEL is on EC2.

Comment: yeah but will I miss anything if I study on this environment?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EC2 however if I remember correctly AWS will charge you extra for using proper RHEL. Without the distribution media you will also not have the lab exercises that are buried in the Extras folder. These exercises are the tasks you will be required to complete to successfully pass the exam. You will also have to make sure the environment is sufficient on your own for each of the tasks.
If you can, get one of the better RHCSA test prep books out there that includes the labs. Even better is to take the RHCSA/RHCE prep class Red Hat does. The instructors will go through every task and be able to assist you if you have questions. Plus the classroom environment is setup properly. You can't go wrong with that!

Good luck and I hope you pass your exam.

Comment: The last time I looked, there was no additional charge for using RHEL on EC2. When did that change?

Comment: So far as I know this has always been the case for many, many moons. 
Here's what AWS says:
https://aws.amazon.com/partners/redhat/faqs/

So far as I know, AWS has always levied additional charges for RHEL to cover the subscriptions.

Comment: Huh? I see nowhere in that page where it says RHEL has additional charges.

Comment: And the [marketplace says](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-lk3liabqn4x2i?sr=0-1&ref_=beagle&applicationId=AWS-Marketplace-Console) it's $0/hr.

Comment: Thank you very much @t3ln3t. I already have access to a cloud guru with exercises, all I need is an environment that will be able to test those.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just find an old x86-64 based laptop / pc, instead of EC2? I don't think you will be able to experience all CentOS/RHEL features in EC2, especially for the stuffs related to baremetal like installation, pxe, etc.

Btw, you can try to use the free developer subscription to get RHEL8 for your laptop/pc. Hope this helps.